# Remove upload button in "el-upload" with list-type="picture-card" from Element Plus when one file uploaded

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, element-plus

I want to remove this empty square when file is already uploaded, and show again, if there is no files. [el-upload file and upload button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BNVL.png)

I wrote this code but it actually do nothing in case of hiding/showing this button.

```
<template>
<el-upload
   v-model:file-list="view1FileList"
   :auto-upload="false"
   list-type="picture-card"
   :on-preview="handlePictureCardPreview"
   :on-change="handleUpload"
   :on-remove="handleRemove"
   :class="{ hideUpload: hideUpload }"
   >
   <i slot="default" class="el-icon-plus"></i>
</el-upload>
</template>

<script>
...
const hideUpload = ref(false);
const handleRemove: UploadProps["onRemove"] = (uploadFile, uploadFiles) => {
  hideUpload.value = false;
  console.log("U CAN upload now");
};
const handleUpload: UploadProps["onChange"] = () => {
  hideUpload.value = true;

  console.log("U CAN'T upload now");
};
</script>
<style>
.hideUpload > div {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Try using `v-if` or `v-show` instead of setting `display:none` through a class, [fallthrough attributes](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html) may not behave as you think they do